# Group matching and unique array elements

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array in php

bobby, kevin, bill, kevin, brian, bobby, bobby

I am trying to anonymise these into

bidder1, bidder2, bidder3, bidder2, bidder4, bidder1, bidder1

I have tried searching the array and try to keep track of the key then piece it back together but I know there is an easier way.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use a temporary array to put the names in. You check if you already find the current name in there, if so, append the index position + 1 to `bidder`. Otherwise, add the name to the temp array, and append the current number of elements in that array.

```
$bidders = $temp = [];
foreach($names as $name) {
   if(false !== ($pos = (array_search($name, $temp)))) {
     $bidders[] = 'bidder'.($pos+1);
   } else {
       $temp[] = $name;
       $bidders[] = 'bidder'.count($temp);
   }
}
var_dump($bidders);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just keep track of who you give numbers to and only increment the "counter" variable when you encounter a new person/bidder.  Prefixing the number with "bidder" is more of the job of your printing layer/logic than your processing logic/layer -- keep the two separate whenever possible.  If you aren't running PHP7.4 or higher, you should upgrade otherwise you'll need to replace the `??=` with an `isset()` condition block with an assignment declaration inside.

PHP 7.4 Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/VASuH))

```
$array = ['bobby', 'kevin', 'bill', 'kevin', 'brian', 'bobby', 'bobby'];
$num = 0;

foreach ($array as $name) {
    $nums[$name] ??= ++$num;
    printf("was: %s, now: bidder%d\n", $name, $nums[$name]);
}
```

Output:

```
was: bobby, now: bidder1
was: kevin, now: bidder2
was: bill, now: bidder3
was: kevin, now: bidder2
was: brian, now: bidder4
was: bobby, now: bidder1
was: bobby, now: bidder1
```

Here is [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72384926/2943403) that leverages the same null coalescing assignment incrementation technique.