# Select top N "ranked" values (with ties) from multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array, ranking

I want to get all rows (in descending order) which have a "score" in the top five of all scores.  Because there may be ties, it is possible that there will be more than 5 rows in the result array.

I have an array in PHP :

```
Array
(
[0] => Array([number] => 1162)
[1] => Array([number] => 1162)
[2] => Array([number] => 1158)
[3] => Array([number] => 1157)
[4] => Array([number] => 1157)
[5] => Array([number] => 1130)
[6] => Array([number] => 1117)
[7] => Array([number] => 1097)
[8] => Array([number] => 1086)
)
```

I want the rows with the top 5 ranks. The final output contains 7 rows because of ties:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array([number] => 1162) #1 Rank
[1] => Array([number] => 1162) #1 Rank
[2] => Array([number] => 1158) #2 Rank
[3] => Array([number] => 1157) #3 Rank
[4] => Array([number] => 1157) #3 Rank
[5] => Array([number] => 1130) #4 Rank
[6] => Array([number] => 1117) #5 Rank
)
```

How can I achieve this? This array value data can be changed according to the situation.

Comment: Yes, so much I write that all works for me but there is an issue. I am unable to predict the array numbers to be come at top 5 ranks

Answer (score 1):

You first need to order the array Desc. Adjust how much ranking you want using the variable `$limit`.

```
<?php
$limit = 5;

$arr = array();
$arr[] = array('number' => 1162);
$arr[] = array('number' => 1162);
$arr[] = array('number' => 1158);
$arr[] = array('number' => 1157);
$arr[] = array('number' => 1157);
$arr[] = array('number' => 1130);
$arr[] = array('number' => 1117);
$arr[] = array('number' => 1097);
$arr[] = array('number' => 1086);

function sortByOrder($a, $b) {
    return $b['number'] - $a['number'];
}
function searchForId($id, $array) {
   foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
       if ($val['number'] === $id) {
           return true;
       }
   }
   return false;
}

usort($arr, 'sortByOrder');
$new_arr = array();
$i = 0;
foreach($arr as $key => $value){
    $checkDuplicate = searchForId($value['number'], $new_arr);
    if(!$checkDuplicate){
        $i++;
    }
    if($i > $limit){
        break;
    }
    $new_arr[] = $value;
}

var_dump($new_arr);
```

Result:

```
array(7) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    ["number"]=>
    int(1162)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["number"]=>
    int(1162)
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    ["number"]=>
    int(1158)
  }
  [3]=>
  array(1) {
    ["number"]=>
    int(1157)
  }
  [4]=>
  array(1) {
    ["number"]=>
    int(1157)
  }
  [5]=>
  array(1) {
    ["number"]=>
    int(1130)
  }
  [6]=>
  array(1) {
    ["number"]=>
    int(1117)
  }
}
```

Demo: https://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/c/49751

Answer (score 0):

Because you array of rows are consistently formatted, you can simply call `rsort()` to natively sort the data in a descending fashion.

Next iterate the sorted array and maintain an incremented "counter" variable (`$rank`) -- only increase this value when a new `$number` is encountered.  So long as the rank of the current number is less than on equal to the `$maxRank`, push the `$number` into the result array.  In other words, when the current rank exceeds the max rank, do not push any more numbers into the result and stop iterating.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/47XoZ))

```
$array = [
    ['number' => 1117],
    ['number' => 1097],
    ['number' => 1162],
    ['number' => 1158],
    ['number' => 1162],
    ['number' => 1157],
    ['number' => 1086],
    ['number' => 1157],
    ['number' => 1130],
];

$maxRank = 5;

rsort($array);  // sort DESC
$rank = 0;
$result = [];
foreach ($array as ['number' => $number]) {
    $ranks[$number] ??= ++$rank;
    if ($ranks[$number] > $maxRank) {
        break;
    }
    $result[] = $number;
}
var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 1162,
  1 => 1162,
  2 => 1158,
  3 => 1157,
  4 => 1157,
  5 => 1130,
  6 => 1117,
)
```

To see how the ranks are distributed without the `break`, see this [demo](https://3v4l.org/tqpPC).